# Owl Carousel implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I can't use the Owl Carousel 2 I would like to use. I think it has something to do witht the files I have connected to my html but there might be a another problem. Do I even have the right files?

This is my HTML so far. I already checked the links to the other files and all of them are correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Mockup</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.css">

</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>


    <footer> 
        <script src="js/plugin/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you  can help me.

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions.  This has nothing to do with [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.  I've retagged your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load **jQuery**!

Try:

```
<footer> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ferrrmolina TY GOOOOOOOD MAN. How did i forget that

Comment: Things that happen. Don't forget to accept the answer :P

Comment: Forrrmolina I would have sooner but you cant answer and accept with in the same 3 min